# Cookies are not being set into deployed website while using ASP.NET framework 4.6.1 and Chrome

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, httpcookie

Httpcookie is not being set in Chrome. It's working as expected in the Mozilla browser. We are using .NET framework 4.6.1.

We wrote the following rewrite rule in `web.config`:

```
<rewrite>
  <outboundRules>
    <rule name="Add SameSite" preCondition="Lax SameSite">
      <match serverVariable="RESPONSE_Set_Cookie" pattern=".*" negate="false" />
      <action type="Rewrite" value="{R:0}; SameSite=Lax" />
      <conditions>
      </conditions>
    </rule>
    <preConditions>
      <preCondition name="Lax SameSite">
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="." />
        <add input="{RESPONSE_Set_Cookie}" pattern="; SameSite=Lax" negate="true" />
      </preCondition>
    </preConditions>
  </outboundRules>
</rewrite>
```

We are using following code to set cookie

```
public void Set(string key, string value, int expireHours = 1)
{
    HttpCookie cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies[Constants.CookieName];

    if (cookie == null)
        cookie = new HttpCookie(Constants.CookieName);

    cookie.Secure = true;
    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(expireHours);
    cookie[key] = value;

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

However, if I set to Secure attribute to false for localhost it's working fine.As our website is hosted on HTTPS so i added cookie.Secure = true; though, This is not working into the chrome browser.We can not update the ASP.NET framework right now.

Any help would be appreciated.Thank you.